# Blazor Server: Changing dynamic component type and accessing it's reference immediately

Tags: blazor

If i change the component type dynamically
`dynCompType = typeof(RubricEditor);`

and then access it's reference to call a method:
`await ((RubricEditor?)_dynComp?.Instance!).ReloadEntity();`

i get an exception, because "_dynComp" is still pointing to the previously rendered component. how can i change the component, wait for re-rendering so the ref is updated, and then call the method in one step?

```
DynamicComponent? _dynComp { get; set; }
    async Task SwitchComponent()
    {
        // dynCompType is "FolderEditor" here -> _dynComp.Instance is of type "FolderEditor"

        // change component type
        dynCompType = typeof(RubricEditor);

        // how to wait here for _dynComp.Instance to change?
        xxxx?

        // this method call fails because instance still is of type FolderEditor
        await ((RubricEditor?)_dynComp?.Instance!).ReloadEntity();
    }
```

i'm following this dynamic component example from the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/dynamiccomponent?view=aspnetcore-7.0

i tried adding
`StateHasChanged(); await Task.Yield();`
between changing the type and accessing .Instance, but this didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the 'Blazor Way' would be to call ReloadEntity in the OnInitialized method of both FolderEditor and RubricEditor.

Something like this...

```
DynamicComponent? _dynComp { get; set; }
    async Task SwitchComponent()
    {
        dynCompType = typeof(RubricEditor);
    }

class RubricEditor : ComponentBase {
    protected void OnInitialized() {
       ReloadEntity();
    }
}
```

Comment: ah, of course. thanks for bringing me back on track. i got confused, because i switch from component a to b (where your OnInitialized solution applies), but sometimes i switch from b to b, but with different parameters. OnInitialized is not called again in this case, but OnParametersSet.... cheers